# How to manually dispatch key event for power button in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to dispatch key event for Power button programatically.I tried following line of code but its not working..

```
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER));
```

But this is not working..

Any help on this most welcome..

Comment: The KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent is used only in the app, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, without custom modification to your firmware or the core of the Android operating system, for a limited number of devices.

Refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button) for more details about POWER button event.