# finish current activity and start another activity when screen being off (black)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i have developed application that consists of A activity (luncher), B activity (second), C activity (third),

what i have tried is :

when the screen is locked or turned off as you are away from the device or have pressed the power button to locked it, my goal is **C activity** finished and when you turn the screen on again **A activity** start.

**Note : i'm new to android and java development .**

i think we can use onPause(), method or onStop(), method for that purpose, but it acually does not work with me as below code in C activity :

```
protected void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  Intent i = new Intent(this,A activity);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

when i lock screen and it become black then open again it still has C activity there.

any advice to get that with onPause(), method or onStop(), method or other ways to get it, thanks

Comment: you required to have a BroadcastReceiver, this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button

Answer (score 0):

in C Activity - onPause method you can try using this code:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

                             @Override
                             public void run()
                             {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this,A activity);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                finish();

                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
```

this will close current activity and open selected activity.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but try this way:-

```
 protected void onPause()
{

    Intent i = new Intent(this,A activity);
   startActivity(i); 
   super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: when i use your code its ok when screen lock and open again it shift to A activity but the problem that code prevent shift from to B activity to C activity also , when press in B activity go directly to A activity also, thanks