# use power button control when screen is sleep

Tags: android, button, sleep

I'm trying to write a android application by using the double click power button to control activity function.

Like this app Speaking Clock: TellMeTheTime (by: Andreas Meyer)

anyone can tell me how to write the java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really override the behavior of the power button [see here for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button)

If you are dead set on using the power button you could try listening for both `SCREEN_ON` and `SCREEN_OFF` events and keeping a timestamp in `SCREEN_ON`. If `SCREEN_OFF` happens within some reasonable time after on did then you could trigger your thing to say the time out load.