# How to disable android hardware buttons programmatically?

Tags: android

I am developing android application with lock functionality. please suggest me how to disable all the hard keys programatically. here i am using beleow code to disable back button. i want like this functionality for all hard keys like home, menu button, Notification bar in android programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

for back button (in activity or fragment)

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

switch( event.getKeyCode() ) {

     case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
         result = true;
        break;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
         result = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        result = true;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        result = true;
        break;
     default:
        result= super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        break;
 }

 return result;
}
```

[and check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button?lq=1)

Comment: can you please try it now ?

Comment: What u have changed? its not working? I want to disable home button click event.

Comment: @user2210356 try this http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-Override-Home-Button-86481.S.153699069

Comment: If you want to disable the home button then you can make your application as default launcher. I tried this on my redmi note 4 and it's working fine. use below codes in start activity tag in the manifest file                                                                                                                
              <!-- The following two intent-filters are the key to set home screen -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />