# How can disable hardware HomeKey and BackKey and Recent Butoom in Android Programitcaly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm setting a new app and want to disable hardware key like home,back and recent key in my app. I found some code in stackoverflow but none of them work.
    Is it possible to disable hardware key?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }



public void onAttachedToWindow() {

          this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock.disableKeyguard();
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296963/how-to-disable-android-hardware-buttons-programmatically

Comment: You can't. If you want to block these keys only in `Samsung Devices`, you can block by `SamsungKNOX`

Comment: Why? Why would you take away basic functionality? Why are you trying to take away the end user's control over their own device?

Answer (score 1):

do nothing in `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
```

add this in `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

and add this in `onPause()`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
 }
```

Comment: what about others? Home and Recent?

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  // super.onBackPressed(); commented this line in order to disable back press
  //Write your code here
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back press disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What about others? Home  And Recent?

Answer (score 0):

You can not block Recent and Home but you can restart activity if user click on Home.

Here is example

**HomeWatcher Class**

```
public class HomeWatcher {

    static final String TAG = "hg";
    private Context mContext;
    private IntentFilter mFilter;
    private OnHomePressedListener mListener;
    private InnerRecevier mRecevier;

    public HomeWatcher(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    }

    public void setOnHomePressedListener(OnHomePressedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mRecevier = new InnerRecevier();
    }

    public void startWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.registerReceiver(mRecevier, mFilter);
        }
    }

    public void stopWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mRecevier);
        }
    }

    class InnerRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = "globalactions";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_LONG_PRESS = "assist";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_VOICE_INTERACTION = "voiceinteraction";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
                if (reason != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "action:" + action + ",reason:" + reason);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                            mListener.onHomePressed();
                        } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                            mListener.onHomeLongPressed();
                        } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_LONG_PRESS)) {
                            mListener.onHomeLongPressed();
                        } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_VOICE_INTERACTION)) {
                            mListener.onHomeLongPressed();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**OnHomePressedListener interface**

```
public interface OnHomePressedListener {

    void onHomePressed();

    void onHomeLongPressed();
}
```

In Your Main Activity

```
HomeWatcher mHomeWatcher = new HomeWatcher(this);
        mHomeWatcher.setOnHomePressedListener(new OnHomePressedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHomePressed() {
                Log.d("Pressed", "Home Button Pressed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onHomeLongPressed() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("LongPressed", "Home Long Button Pressed");
            }
        });
        mHomeWatcher.startWatch();
```