# Is It Possible for an Android App to Ignore All Physical User Input?

Tags: android

I want to try to make an Android alarm app that is impossible to stop. In other words, it keeps going for a predetermined amount of time, even if the user presses the power button, tries to reduce the volume, or anything else.
It does not seem feasible to me, but since I have very little Android experience, I'd like to know if something like that is theoretically able to be done. Thanks.

Comment: I hope it is not possible or at least very difficult to do. Something like this could be abused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been addressed on SO here: [Override Power button just like Home button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10077905/2540235)
.

There are several answers in the link that will give you options and get you 90% of the way there, but no answer will cover all devices/scenarios. The accepted answer in the link puts it best:

> The Android system, as far as is documented, defines *(a physical button press)* as a
>   broadcast action. Following the publish-subscribe pattern of message
>   propagation, this message will notify all concerned parties of this
>   action. Because this message is sent by the system, because the
>   message stack is managed by the system, and because the message is
>   also received by the system, your code simply *(cannot be)* injected in the
>   right place to block the reception of this message.